# Questions about dynamically creating divtags

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, html-table

I'm trying to dynamically create divtags for each cell of my table so that I can later fill them in with other stuff. However, when I tried doing this:

```
newhtml+="<div id ='" + (j) +"'><td class = 'unselected'>&nbsp?&nbsp</td></div>"
```

and later using it it acted as if it never created it.

So after browsing stackoverflow I found out that you should use this line of code to dynamically create a div tag:

```
var divtag = document.createElement('div');
```

But my question is how do I implement it into my js code?

Here is the section of code that is supposed to create divtags for later referencing:

```
newhtml+="<tr>";
for (var j = 0; j < $tblcols; j++){
newhtml+="<div id ='" + (j) +"'><td class = 'unselected'>&nbsp?&nbsp</td></div>";
```

And here is the section that uses it:

```
divtag = document.getElementById("'" + (++$counter2) + "'");
newhtml +="<td class = 'solved'><img src ='sc2units/" + $counter2 + ".jpg'></td>";
divtag.innerHTML = newhtml;
```

each section is a nested for loop that goes through the entire array of data that needs outputted.

EDIT: If there is an easier way to fill cells with data in an array I would be happy to know.

Comment: Your HTML structure is invalid. [`<td>` tags must be inside of a `<tr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td), not a `<div>`. You could put your `<div>`s inside  the `<td>`s, but not immediately outside. Looks like you could simply omit the `<div>`s and put the IDs on the `<td>` elements.

Comment: Please post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your problem.

Comment: The <td> tags are a part of the nested loop, I omitted that section for brevtiy. The overall structure goes like this: <table><tr><div><td></td></div></tr></table>
is that incorrect? I thought divs were more flexible.

Comment: could I put a <div> inside the td's?
But I would like to know more about how to dynamically create tags in general, then.

Comment: Yes, incorrect. It must be `<table><tr><td>[ content ]</td></tr></table>`. "[ content ]" can include divs, h1s more tables, anything. You can have multiple `<td>` siblings and `<tr>` siblings - I just have one of each

Comment: So do you guys think it's just a html error and not a coding error? Because I put the <div> tags back and it still isn't working. It says that the data in divtag is still null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure on your table, or setup, or exact needs.... But I believe you want to give content to certain table cells after you've already created the cells. You're on to the right idea with naming them, but you can't wrap `<td>`s in `<div>`s so your next best option is to simply name the <`td>`s themselves.

You could also add the content right inside the second loop, but we'll run with this.

**HTML**

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>[ content ]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>[ content ]</td>
        <td>[ content ]</td>
    </tr>
    [ etc ]
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable"),
    rows = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr");

// loop all rows
for (var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++){

    // loop all cols within the row
    var cols = rows[r].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var c = 0; c < cols.length; c++){
        cols[c].id = "row-" + r + "_col-" + c;
    }
}

// usage
document.getElementById("row-1_col-1").innerHTML = "JS POWER";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/tJYNM/

Answer (score 0):

You can create the elements separately then organize them later, inserting one inside the other. Something like:

```
var mydiv = document.createElement("DIV");
var mytd = document.createElement("TD");
mytd.innerHTML = "some basic text";
mydiv.appendChild(mytd);  // insert the TD inside the DIV
document.body.appendChild(mydiv);  // insert the DIV in the document's body
```

I just don't know what's about putting TD's inside DIV's...

Comment: but where in the body will it be inserted?

Comment: Because I already generated a table and I want the div tags to hold the td's